# How to stop an indeterminate ProgressBar animation?

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, progress-bar

I don't know if i'm missing some obvious method/property, but here it is:
I have a ProgressBar, which has the property IsIndeterminate as true by default. But I want it's animation only in a certain period. How can I achieve that?
I tried something like:

```
SomeBackgroundWorker.DoWork += SomeBackgroundWorker_DoWork;
pgbStatus.IsIndeterminate = true;
btnUpdate.IsEnabled = false;
SomeBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
btnUpdate.IsEnabled = true;
pgbStatus.IsIndeterminate = false;
```

But then it wouldn't move. Sorry if it's a duplicate(I have the feeling it is), but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: As soon as `SomeBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();` is called then you are immediately calling `pgbStatus.IsIndeterminate = false;` so it will stop... You need to stop only after the async task has completed.

Comment: God, I do feel stupid now. Thank you, could you also post this as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place

```
btnUpdate.IsEnabled = true;
pgbStatus.IsIndeterminate = false;
```

In the end of `SomeBackgroundWorker` `DoWork()` method instead.
Probably you will need `Invoke()` to UI thread also.

Comment: Got it, but I placed it on RunWorkedCompleted, to avoid dispatching. Thanks!